# Is the interval variable considered as a type of numerical variable or ordinal variable?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a fundamental question about interval variable and I have searched about it in different tutorials but still not sure.

*"An interval scale is one where **there is order** and the difference between two values is meaningful."* from [graphpad.com](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-ordinal-interval-and-ratio-variables-why-should-i-care/)

*"The interval variable is a measurement variable that is used to define values measured along a scale, with each point placed at **an equal distance from one another**. It is one of the 2 types of numerical variables and is an extension of the ordinal variable."* from [formpl.us](https://www.formpl.us/blog/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-variable-example)

My question is about the last sentence above, which states that interval variable is numerical and an extension of ordinal. If we have an atribute 'age' as follows:

[image]

Then based on the given definitions above, "age" must be an interval attribute. However, doesn't it seem to be more ordinal than numerical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formal definition of an interval (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))):

> In mathematics, a (real) interval is a set of real numbers that
> contains all real numbers lying between any two numbers of the set.
> For example, the set of numbers x satisfying 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 is an interval
> which contains 0, 1, and all numbers in between.

This definition doesn't tell us what to do to represent an interval for ML purposes... and that's normal :)

For ML purposes we need to decide a suitable **representation**, and there's rarely a mathematically pure or unique way to represent a mathematical object. Your confusion comes from the fact that the sites you mention propose their own representation, i.e. they consider a particular definition of interval, presumably because it suits their goal. The second one in particular is clearly defining an "interval variable" as an object in a particular language, with constraints which have nothing to do with the above definition.

Now to answer your question: an interval is not atomic, since it's not a single value. So strictly speaking it's neither a numerical nor an ordinal.

But you're probably not very satisfied with this answer, since you still want to be able to use this kind of feature. How? As usual, it depends:

- Most of the time an interval can be **converted** to an ordinal value (note that it's a conversion, i.e. we simplify the data to make it usable). The conversion to ordinal is typically done by numbering the possible intervals (following their order) with integers. If the variable is going to be a label in a classification task, it can even be converted to a categorical variable.
- However there are cases where an ordinal would not be a good representation, in particular if the intervals are not equal and the ML method involves distances. In such cases it's probably safer to convert the interval to a numerical value, typically the mean of the interval. This way both order and distances are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant Wikipedia page is [Level of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement). Its section on the interval level of measurement has a number of instructive examples and a single bad one, the Celsius scale. It started as insufficient and ended at more than necessary.

Originally, it "tried" to be an interval scale, that is, **with meaningful comparison of differences**. The endpoints, 0 °C and 100 °C, were well defined, but the meaning of 50 °C depended on the materials used for the thermometer. For a long time, it was mercury, the thermal expansion of which was *arbitrarily defined* to be linear. Today, with the temperature being defined as thermodynamic temperature (mean energy per degree of freedom) and a degree Celsius equal to a degree Kelvin, **50 °C has shifted by a small amount**.

Only since that change, it is valid to say that the interval from 0 °C to 50 °C is of the same size as the difference between 50 °C and 100 °C.

But more than that: It is valid to state that 100 °C is hotter than 0 °C by the factor 373.15/273.15, since absolute zero (0 K) is well defined: Even the weakest oscillators are in their ground state. This qualifies the thermodynamic temperature as a ratio scale, a higher level of measurement than interval scales.

EDIT: Now to your original question,

> doesn't it seem to be more ordinal than numerical?

No, age intervals have a meaningful size, while on an ordinal scale, interval size is meaningless. Remember that these are levels of measurement, not evaluation.

Age has even been regarded as a ratio scale, but that is debatable since the progress of both [Neonatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neonatology) (a premature infant is obviously not of the same age as a normal newborn) and [Cryoconservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoconservation_of_animal_genetic_resources).